# how to include an external apk in a Maven Appium project

Tags: java, android, eclipse, git, maven

I have an Appium Java project in Eclipse which tests an Android Apk. 
I converted my initial project to a Maven project, so I have only "src" folder which contains all the test classes.

Till now I was using a local copy of the Apk to perform Appium tests on it.

I would like Maven will add the Apk automatically from a remote location as a dependency to the project tree and include it in the build process.

1) Is it possible to use Git as a remote location?

2) Can you please suggest me how to modify the pom.xml file so it will add the Apk to the build process?

Comment: better to show your current pj structure...

Comment: Sorry, what is pj?

Comment: current project structure